# Hiding files at kernel level security

Tags: c++, c

Friends, I am developing a software in which I need to hide files at kernel level.I tried to do that using SSDT Hooking but I am not getting enough resources that how to get started.

Any suggestions or code snippets will be helpful...thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "hiding files at kernel level"?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "I need to hide files at kernel level"? Which kernel are you talking about? Linux? L4? Mach? Xnu? DragonflyBSD? Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please explain why the already available hiding via `.` at the start of file names is not useable for you. Also please elaborate on why hiding files any more completely than provided that way is needed. Files hidden from the user would for example be a problem for virus scanning and other malware defense mechansims. And of course you are not doing anything like intentionally creating ways to support malware or hiding malware, are you? Please explain for what goodware (i.e. opposite of malware) this hiding would be needed? Why would users want files better hidden from them than by `.naming`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Aksing for an MRE is appropriate for quesitons on misbehaviour of existing code. What kind of MRE do you expect for this "no idea how to start" question?

Answer (score 1):

Going with SSDT hooks is not the best idea, not only will you have to disable Patchguard but there's a Microsoft approved solution that's more effective anyway. What you want is a File System Minifilter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/file-system-minifilter-drivers